# TimeServiceProvider can't be assigned to the list type SingleChildWidget

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

The following Flutter code is for a Stopwatch that persistently can run in the background. It works great when I use only one provider:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    TimerServiceProvider(
      service: TimerService(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class TimerService extends ChangeNotifier {
  Stopwatch _watch;
  Timer _timer;

  Duration get currentDuration => _currentDuration;
  Duration _currentDuration = Duration.zero;

  bool get isRunning => _timer != null;

  TimerService() {
    _watch = Stopwatch();
  }

  void _onTick(Timer timer) {
    _currentDuration = _watch.elapsed;

    // notify all listening widgets
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void start() {
    if (_timer != null) return;

    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), _onTick);
    _watch.start();

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void stop() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = null;
    _watch.stop();
    _currentDuration = _watch.elapsed;

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void reset() {
    stop();
    _watch.reset();
    _currentDuration = Duration.zero;

    notifyListeners();
  }

  static TimerService of(BuildContext context) {
    var provider =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<TimerServiceProvider>();
    return provider.service;
  }
}

class TimerServiceProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  const TimerServiceProvider({Key key, this.service, Widget child})
      : super(key: key, child: child);

  final TimerService service;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(TimerServiceProvider old) => service != old.service;
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Service Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var timerService = TimerService.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: timerService, // listen to ChangeNotifier
          builder: (context, child) {
            // this part is rebuilt whenever notifyListeners() is called
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Elapsed: ${timerService.currentDuration}'),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: !timerService.isRunning
                      ? timerService.start
                      : timerService.stop,
                  child: Text(!timerService.isRunning ? 'Start' : 'Stop'),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: timerService.reset,
                  child: Text('Reset'),
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, I need to use more than one provider in my app and when I wrap this provider in a MultiProvider I get an error saying that error: The element type 'TimerServiceProvider' can't be assigned to the list type 'SingleChildWidget'. (list_element_type_not_assignable

The code I used to wrap the provider in a MultiProvider looks as follows:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
      MultiProvider(
          providers: [
          TimerServiceProvider(service: TimerService(),
          ),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),)
  );
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `ChangeNotifierProvider` and `Provider.of<TimerService>` 
code snippet

```
void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => TimerService()),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}
...

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var timerService = Provider.of<TimerService>(context, listen: false);
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => TimerService()),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class TimerService extends ChangeNotifier {
  Stopwatch _watch;
  Timer _timer;

  Duration get currentDuration => _currentDuration;
  Duration _currentDuration = Duration.zero;

  bool get isRunning => _timer != null;

  TimerService() {
    _watch = Stopwatch();
  }

  void _onTick(Timer timer) {
    _currentDuration = _watch.elapsed;

    // notify all listening widgets
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void start() {
    if (_timer != null) return;

    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), _onTick);
    _watch.start();

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void stop() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = null;
    _watch.stop();
    _currentDuration = _watch.elapsed;

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void reset() {
    stop();
    _watch.reset();
    _currentDuration = Duration.zero;

    notifyListeners();
  }

  /*static TimerService of(BuildContext context) {
    var provider =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<TimerServiceProvider>();
    return provider.service;
  }*/
}

class TimerServiceProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  const TimerServiceProvider({Key key, this.service, Widget child})
      : super(key: key, child: child);

  final TimerService service;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(TimerServiceProvider old) => service != old.service;
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Service Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var timerService = Provider.of<TimerService>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: timerService, // listen to ChangeNotifier
          builder: (context, child) {
            // this part is rebuilt whenever notifyListeners() is called
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Elapsed: ${timerService.currentDuration}'),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: !timerService.isRunning
                      ? timerService.start
                      : timerService.stop,
                  child: Text(!timerService.isRunning ? 'Start' : 'Stop'),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: timerService.reset,
                  child: Text('Reset'),
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an excellent solution! Greatly appreciated. After using the code, I realized that I need a few more lines of code to be executed whenever the onTap is done on the Start/Stop button. I tried using () { timerService.start; additional code lines; } and then receive an error "Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose()". Any suggestions for how I solve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Need to reproduce. Could you post reproduce code to a new question? thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Very grateful for your help. I posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63469724/persistent-stopwatch-with-several-lines-of-code-executed-upon-onpress-start-stop